# How do people know how big the rocks are in the photos of Titan's surface?

Tags: imaging, camera, titan, huygens-lander

How do people know how big the rocks are in the photos of Titan's surface?

[image: Small rocks, possibly made of water ice, at the Huygens landing site. Evidence of erosion at the base of these objects suggests fluvial activity. The right panel shows, approximately, the true color of the scene.]

Comment: I'm guessing it's a simple matter of knowing the camera's designed field of view & some form of rangefinding--or not even that: note that the angle horizon is measured out. Assuming the ground is flat, you only need to know the distance to the horizon (size of Titan & the height of the camera will get you that) to figure out the distance of everything else. If you know the distance of an object & the angular fov it occupies, it's just trig to figure out the size of the object. But I have absolutely no source to know that's what huygens actually did, so here's a comment & not an answer!

Comment: I'm guessing you should make that an answer, @AntonHengst.

Comment: "photogammetry" may be a relevant search term.